# What is the behavior of Promtail when it encounters a compressed folder like .tar.gz or .zip

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

How does promtail read the files inside a compressed (.zip or .tar or .tar.gz) folder? Does it at all monitor the compressed files or not?

I have made an environment for promtail to monitor a folder that has three types of folders inside it - .zip folder, .tar.gz folder and a normal folder all of which contains .log files.
The RegEx configured in Promtail is as /*path*/switch/**/*.log  (switch contains the 3 types of folders)

Now, I expected it to read the log files inside the .tar.gz and the normal folder. It cannot read the .zip folder as mentioned in the document link here by Grafana [https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/#:~:text=.tar.gz%3A%20Data,the%20near%20future](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/#:%7E:text=.tar.gz%3A%20Data,the%20near%20future).

However, it is not reading any of the compressed file formats. It is just reading the log files present in the normal folder. I checked this through the Position.yaml file of promtail.

How can I make Promtail read the log files present inside the .tar.gz folder?

Comment: Note that .tar.gz and .zip files are files, and not folders. From what I've understood from the page you've linked, .tar.gz files are processed exactly as .gz files, except that because the tar format adds metadata at the beginning, there will be some unwanted text at the beginning of the first log entry. It seems that your regex is wrong if you were expecting it to extract files from the tar archive and look at the extracted file extensions. It will simply look at the tar file as a file itself. Therefore it won't match "*.log".